# Why can't I get a image (base64 string) to display

Tags: javascript, react-pdf

I am having a bit of trouble getting an Image to display. While normally, I would display the image like this:

```js
<img src={"data:image/png;base64," + data.image} id="logoImg" />
```

... where data.image is a base64 string. However, this gives me no error but I never see the logo on the pdf:

```
<Image style={styles.logo} src={{ data: "image/png;base64," + data.image}} />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is image tag In uppercase **<Image**

Comment: @MpenduloPhilipSibiya Because it belongs to react-pdf. [<Image...>](https://react-pdf.org/components#image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Original Image was a jpeg
2. I had to put it in a buffer first.

```
const buff = new Buffer(data.image, 'base64');
...
<Image style={styles.logo} src={{ data: buff, format: 'jpg' }} />
```